# Minimum hardware requirements for ElasticSearch in docker

Tags: memory, hardware, elasticsearch

I am developing a search application using elasticsearch and I would like to keep the development cost as low as possible. What are the minimum  requirements for elasticsearch to run properly inside a docker container?

I am especially interested in the RAM as I believe this is the bottle neck.

I have been looking all over the place for this, but I can't seem to find *any* documentation on the minimum hardware requirements for elasticsearch what so ever. Maybe my googlefu isn't good enough, or maybe everyone working on elasticsearch have a big server budget.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html docker is incidental.

Comment: I have read that document, but nowhere does it mention the minimum requirements. It says `A machine with 64 GB of RAM is the ideal sweet spot, but 32 GB and 16 GB machines are also common.`, all of which appears to be orders of magnitude more that what should be the minimum.

Comment: Test it with your hardware and your expected load. Increase hardware resources until you get the performance you need.